# How to UPDATE table with changing values

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Hi I want to update a column to some values that can be changed during the update. e.g.

```
1: select * into #TempTable from (values ('a', 1), ('b', 1)) t (code, num)
2: select * from #TempTable
3: update tt set tt.code = 'b', tt.num = (
     select max(oo.num) + 1 from #TempTable oo where oo.code = 'b')
   from #TempTable tt
4: select * from #TempTable
5: drop table #TempTable
```

The output of statement 2: is

```
code num
---- ---
a    1
b    1
```

and statement 4: is

```
code num
---- ---
b    2
b    2
```

it seems as if the UPDATE statement is static, resulting both 'b' with num 2. What I really want to achieve is column num will change its value through out the whole UPDATE statement, i.e. for statement 4: I expect the output to be

```
code num
---- ---
b    2
b    3
```

How do you write the query to achieve that? I would like to avoid using cursors, hence answers without relying on cursors will be picked. If not possible without cursors, only then answers with cursors will be picked. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't possible without cursors as a general requirement. Conceptually a SQL update happens "all at once". The concept of "Halloween Protection" is all about ensuring that this can not happen in real world execution plans. For some specific types of requirement - e.g. running totals it would be possible to use window functions to end up with the same result however.

Answer (score -1):

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT Code 
     , Num
     , Num + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Num ASC) rn
FROM #TempTable )
UPDATE CTE 
  SET Code = 'b'
     ,Num = rn
```

Comment: Sorry I put your code into my example above it still gives two 'b', 2

Comment: Try now @user1589188 (Instead of down voting people who are trying to help you, you should help them with proper feedback and more information to help you)

Comment: Thanks for trying, but your answer is artificial and you got my question wrong. You simply pre-select 2, and 3 and update the num column to 2 and 3. My question is about updating a column to value that is changing through out the whole update.